# Are itemize and EBGaramond compatible?

Tags: fonts, symbols, pdftex, ebgaramond

This MWE works:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Here is some plain text in Garamond
\end{document}
```

But it I put the text in itemize like this:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here is some plain text in Garamond
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Font family `TS1+EBGaramond-LF' unknown.
```

This is using pdflatex and texlive 2013 on fedora.

It *does* compile with luatex or xetex

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an edited version of your example that should theoretically work with all engines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi\fi

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here is some plain text in Garamond
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However, there is a bug in the distributed file `TS1EBGaramond-OsF.fd` where the last few lines have `LF` instead of `OsF`: it should be

```
%% Generated by autoinst on 2013/02/13
%%
\ProvidesFile{TS1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
    [2013/02/13 (autoinst)  Font definitions for TS1/EBGaramond-OsF.]

\expandafter\ifx\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\EBGaramond@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\EBGaramond@@scale{s*[\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-ts1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-ts1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}

\endinput
```

but the last seven `\DeclareFontShape` declarations have `LF` instead of `OsF` in all places. Probably that part has been copied by the similar `TS1EBGaramond-LF.fd` and not edited.

Therefore you get the error message you mention when compiling with `pdflatex`, because the font description file refers to an unknown font family.

There are some possible workarounds.

1. Copy the distributed `TS1EBGaramond-OsF.fd` file to the document directory and edit it so that it appears as above.
2. Directly edit the distributed file (risky)
3. Add the necessary code to keep `pdflatex` happy:

   ```
   \documentclass[english]{article}
   \usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

   \ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \fi\fi

   \usepackage{babel}

   \usepackage{ebgaramond}

   \ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else
     \normalfont
     \makeatletter
     \input{TS1EBGaramond-LF.fd}
     \input{TS1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
     \makeatother
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
     \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
   \fi\fi


   \begin{document}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Here is some plain text in Garamond
   \end{itemize}

   \end{document}
   ```

In any case, you should mention the problem to the package maintainer.

Comment: Thanks. This works, as does Herbert's workaround. Should I report to the texlive mailing list or to the author listed on ctan? If the latter, how do I make contact?

Comment: @user8786: To the author if possible. The (documentation of) the package should have contact information for the author. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user8786".

Comment: Note that the version of the EBGaramond support package released 2014/06/22 has fixed the problem

Comment: @egreg Which version of TeX Live is the fix in?

Answer (score 6):

`\textbullet` is not defined. Use

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\bullet$}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here is some plain text in Garamond
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

or use

```
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
```

then it defines `\textbullet`.

By the way: Using `luainputenc` with `utf8` makes no sense. utf is used by default. And a version for all engines is:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\fi\fi
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here is some plain text in Garamond
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

this runs with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`

Comment: I would recommend to define `\textbillet` instead:  `\def\textbullet{$\bullet$}`

Comment: Of course `\textbullet` *is* defined. The error has nothing to do with the fact it is defined or not.